# jQuery .load() wait, before load content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fadeOut the #portfolio-wrapper, than load the portfolio2.html with fadeIn(600). The problem is that the load function execute before the fadeOut(600).
Please help me! Big thanks :)

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio-wrapper").fadeOut(600).load('portfolio2.html').fadeIn(600);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use callbacks:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("#portfolio-wrapper").fadeOut(600, function() {
        $(this).load('portfolio2.html', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(600);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a problem... When the content fades out, the #portfolio-wrapper div loose the height, and the page jumps to top, than loads portfolio2.html...

Comment: @myrandom You could specify a min-height for your wrapper.